# How do I customize my WACOM Tablet express keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, tablet, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos S CTL-4100 that I'm trying to use in Ubuntu 19.04. The tablet and pen seem to be recognized by the OS, but when I try to customize the buttons in the system settings, pressing the buttons does nothing.
I'd like to be able to assign common key commands to the buttons like ctrl-z and such, or be able to have the software I'm using (gimp or krita) recognize the inputs and assign functions in the software to the keys on the tablet.

It may be a long shot, but with the windows driver, I can have a radial menu come up when I press a key, if that's possible, I'd love that.

Answer (score 1):

If the WACOM Tablet settings don't work consistantly, or for the kind of key combos you want (e.g. Ctrl)  You can try using the [xsetwacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Tablet-Configuration-1%3A-xsetwacom-and-xorg.conf).

For example, to set button 1 to Ctrl + Z you could run this in the terminal:

`xsetwacom set "Wacom BambooFun 2FG 4x5 Finger pad" Button 1 "key ctrl z"`

Here's a tutorial that walks you through it and shows you how to create a script to run it automatically:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEZK7reJqoQ&list=PLaGRTLvEbVzxF5tGBZ_M6Prvc8dz8bOxl&index=5

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the Settings->Devics->Wacom-tablet entry provides two panels chosen from the top menu bar, namely "Pen" and "Tablet-PC".

The "Tablet-PC" panel has an "Assign buttons..." button which opens a visual display of the buttons you have on your Wacom.  If you press a button, you are allowed to choose from a drop-down menu several items, one being "Assign key combination..." with a text box for the key combination.

This is what I think you are talking about.

Unfortunately, from my brief experiments, Ubuntu only allows for a key *combination* like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-K, and not just a modfier key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>.  I think this is unfortunate, as the default button binding under Windows 10 is exactly those modifier keys, but perhaps those who did that settings panel had not actually used a Wacom tablet so they wouldn't know.